# IJulia install - WARNING: Module BinDeps uuid did not match cache file

Tags: julia

After running `Pkg.update()` I ran into the following error message regarding IJulia installation:

```
WARNING: Module BinDeps uuid did not match cache file
===============================[ ERROR: IJulia ]================================

LoadError: __precompile__(true) but require failed to create a precompiled cache file
while loading /home/om/.julia/v0.4/IJulia/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 2

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: IJulia had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /home/om/.julia/v0.4
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("IJulia")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
```

Anyone knows what could be the problem here?

Comment: try running  `Pkg.build("IJulia")` as julia suggested.

Comment: I think you just need to restart the notebook.

Comment: Running `Pkg.build("IJulia")` yields the same error again.

Comment: Restarting Julia solved it for me. It seems to be a known [bug](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13200).

Answer (score 1):

I have fought installing IJulia for few hours and my arrival here was the first starting point. Now, after this cumbersome process, I have decided that this info could be useful for the next generations:

- Windows 10, non-English ...
- Installed Julia 0.4.2 on some local folder: `<julia>`
- Made folder `<julia>\env`

  - Made folder `<julia>\env\home` a.k.a. `<home>`
  - Made folder `<julia>\env\appdata` a.k.a. `<appdata>`
- Invoke `set HOME=<appdata>&& set APPDATA=<appdata>&& <julia>/bin/julia.exe` Note that I had to glue the `&&` to the paths due to my specific call (I was using [Cmder](http://cmder.net/)). Julia interestingly - did not cut the whitespace at the end.
- When inside Julia's command line interpreter:

  - `Pkg.add("IJulia")` - it will break after while
  - `Pkg.rm("IJulia")`
  - `Pkg.add("IJulia")`

Voila! Now I want to figure out whether I can put this on FreeBSD, behind a public server.

Most of the issues were related to my environment being non-English and hence the HOME and APPDATA environment variables were screwing some Python code - they expect ASCII chars on the paths.