# PyCall fails to build in julia under Linuxmint 17.2

Tags: matplotlib, julia, linux-mint

Trying out julia-0.4 in Linuxmint 17.2, from the live disk. Installed it ok, added the ODE package ok and used it, tried to add PyPlot but it fails, even after suggested check and rebuild:

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: No packages to install, update or remove

julia> Pkg.build("PyCall")
INFO: Building PyCall
INFO: Recompiling stale cache file /home/mint/.julia/lib/v0.4/Conda.ji for module Conda.
WARNING: Module BinDeps uuid did not match cache file
WARNING: deserialization checks failed while attempting to load cache from /home/mint/.julia/lib/v0.4/Conda.ji
INFO: Precompiling module Conda...
INFO: Recompiling stale cache file /home/mint/.julia/lib/v0.4/Conda.ji for module Conda.
WARNING: Module BinDeps uuid did not match cache file
===============================[ ERROR: PyCall ]================================

LoadError: __precompile__(true) but require failed to create a precompiled cache file
while loading /home/mint/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 12

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: PyCall had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /home/mint/.julia/v0.4
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("PyCall")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33594644/2068635).

Comment: Answering my own question --- problem solved by repeated effort. It seems that if matplotlib itself is absent, adding it after a failed PyPlot installation doesn't work. Pkg.rm("PyPlot"), followed by shutting down julia, and then Pkg.add("PyPlot") did the trick